# Polar form of $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Write the following in polar form:$$\frac{1}{z}$$

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+yi}$$

$$\frac{1}{x+yi}\cdot \frac{x-yi}{x-yi}=\frac{x-yi}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x-yi}{r^2}$$

Because:

$$x-yi=rcis(-\frac{\pi}{4})$$

We get:

$$\frac{rcis(-\frac{\pi}{4})}{r^2}=\frac{cis(-\frac{\pi}{4})}{r}$$

Is the following correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why $\textrm{cis}\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ appears here: Since every nonzero complex number is invertible, this would imply that every complex number has argument $-\frac{\pi}{4}$, which isn't the case.

**Hint** If we write $z$ in polar form, as $r e^{i\theta}$, how can we write $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{r e^{i \theta}}$ in polar form, i.e., as $\rho e^{i \alpha}$ for appropriate real $\rho, \alpha$?

Comment: So it will be $\rho e^{-ia}$? and in the form of $r$ and $cis$ it is $rcis(-\theta)$?

Comment: The quantity $frac{1}{z}$ is characterized by $z \cdot \frac{1}{z} = 1$, or in polar form, $(r e^{i \theta})(\rho e^{i \alpha}) = 1$. So, we need to find expressions for $\rho, \alpha$ in terms of $r, \theta$ that make this equation true.

Comment: The first equation in the previous comment should have been $\frac{1}{z}$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

write $\frac{1}{z}=z^{-1}$ for $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ using the property of exponents $(x^n)^m=x^{nm}$.